# Re-order or sort line by line

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I have a file of genomic coordinates structured like this:

```
chromosome1|25000|35000_chromosome1|400|600
chromosome4|78000|80000_chromosome2|43000|45000
```

I want to sort the 2 entries on each line to have them ordered by lower genomic coordinates first, if they belong to the same chromosome (e.g. line 1) or by chromosome with lower number first, if they are on different chromosomes.
Desired output:

```
chromosome1|400|600_chromosome1|25000|35000
chromosome2|43000|45000_chromosome4|78000|80000
```

I have tried the following but strangely enough it does not always work correctly!

`cat file | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{split($1,a,"_chr"); a[2]="chr" a[2]; str=$1; if(a[1]>a[2]) str=a[2]"_"a[1]; print str,$2}'`

Can please somebody help?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "_"}                # use "_" as a delimiter
{
    split($1, a, "\\|")                    # split left genomic coordinates with "|" and assign array "a"
    split($2, b, "\\|")                    # split right genomic coordinates with "|" and assign array "b"
    if (a[1] == b[1]) {                    # if they belong to the same chromosome
        if (a[2] < b[2]) print $1, $2      # then compare lower genomic coordinates
        else print $2, $1
    } else {                               # they belong to different chromosomes
        sub(/^[^0-9]+/, "", a[1])          # extract chromosome number and overwrite a[1]
        sub(/^[^0-9]+/, "", b[1])          # extract chromosome number and overwrite b[1]
        if (a[1]+0 < b[1]+0) print $1, $2  # then compare the numbers
        else print $2, $1
    }
}' file
```

Output for the given sample file:

```
chromosome1|400|600_chromosome1|25000|35000
chromosome2|43000|45000_chromosome4|78000|80000
```

Comment: Added note: with the above script I was getting the warning "awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|', hence I just removed the backslashes in split($1, a, "\|") and split($1, b, "\|"). Thanks again!

Comment: Oddly enough: I've completed running the script on all my files and there are several cases for which it does not work...I am not really sure why. Here is one example that is not correctly processed: `chromosome17|36695929|36696217_chromosome3|189667168|189667457` Any idea why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for testing and sorry for bothering you. In the comparison line
`if (a[1] < b[1]) ...` we expect the numerical comparison is performed.
However it seems some versions of `awk` performs string comparison here
by some reason. (Maybe a[1] and b[1] used to be a string before the
sub() operation. This may be a bug of `awk` anyway.)
As a workaround, let us force a numerical context by adding "0" to these
variables here.
In addition, as for the "|" issue, it will be robust to say "\\|" instead.
I have updated my answer with these modifications. Hope it will work now. BR.

Comment: I'll try the new version, in the meanwhile thank you very much for your kindness and the thorough explanation, I've learned a lot. Cheers!